# My App suddenly returns 500 error

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Today, my Application (http://nou-shindan.appspot.com/) returns 500 error.
Error logs here but we haven't done any update for more than a year.

Is there a change to the specification of the **AppEngine**?

```
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (34f6450412a1bd58) started at 2013/09/23 01:47:50.230 UTC and was still executing at 2013/09/23 01:48:49.809 UTC.
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-34f6450412a1bd58(Request.java)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:57)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:476)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:259)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:273)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.slim3.util.CipherFactory.getFactory(CipherFactory.java:40)
    at com.aimlucklab.firstherrmann.filter.FacebookFilter.doFilter(FacebookFilter.scala:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: What does your application do? Does it change overtime (ie store data, get data from external source, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Post your web.xml and then also your entry point servlet, something in your entry servlet is taking longer than 30 seconds which is causing a timeout.